# NavigationLink contentShape not working without adding a background color

Tags: swiftui

I wanted to know why the contentShape is not working for NavigationLink in SwiftUI without a background color. I'm not sure if I'm adding the contentShape in the right place but it is not working for me unless I add a background color. This is how my code looks, uncomment a line and the contentShape will work on the NavigationLink.

```
struct TV4: View {
    @State var tfText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                //                Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea()
                
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    Text("Enter your name")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    TextField("Name", text: $tfText)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .frame(height: 44)
                        .background(.green, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous))
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: {Color.red.ignoresSafeArea()}) {
                        Text("Next")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .frame(height: 44)
                            .background(.red, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous))
                    }
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                //                .background(.blue)
            }
            //            .background(.blue)
            .navigationTitle("Hello")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect from contentShape here? NavigationLink is-a button, it does not need extra content shape to work. And what do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: The thing is that the NavigationLink is clickable outside the bounds. I thought by adding the contentShape would work. Now it does work if I add a background

Comment: Which background? There are many in your code snapshot. Next button works ok, but if I comment contentShape... it woks ok as well, actually as expected.

Comment: You just have to uncomment one doesn't matter which one. That odd, in which device are you running it on? Im running it on the simulator iPhone 13 iOS 15.5 and its making the NavigationLink clickable outside of its bounds.

Comment: Xcode 14 / iOS 16

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5 as well.

Comment: Hmm. I just ran it on my physical phone and it works just fine. Im running Xcode 13.4.1 so not sure if its because of that. [Here is a recording on what was going on.](https://youtube.com/shorts/DIN_X6FG7TQ?feature=share) Next time I know to run it on my actual phone before posting. Thanks @Asperia.